# XCode inserting data via iphone into mysql database response

Tags: php, ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have been looking online and doing research on different ways to connect to webpages (.php file in my case) to insert data into mysql database. My code works and successfully inserts data I type in to the field, however, I would like to be able to notify the user that the name has successfully been inserted into the database with no errors, and if there is an error spit out an error. Here is the code that is working (it inserts whatever name user types into my database):

```
- (IBAction)addButton:(id)sender {

NSString *name = self.MYSQLfield.text;
NSLog(@"%@", name);
// create string contains url address for php file, the file name is insert.php, it receives parameter :name
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://twochicken.com:8080/insert.php?name=%@",name];
// to execute php code
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

// to receive the returend value
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", strResult);

}
```

I've seen some people doing it with NSURLConnection method, and get response codes from the request they make, but I'm not doing it (my php file takes care of the POSTS) this way so i am wondering if I am doing it the right way.

Again my question is how can I let the user know they have successfully inserted into the database? (I am hoping with a popup saying insert has been completed, after button has been pressed, but I need a way to get the return value of the page request.)

Comment: use UIAlertView to display the successfully message

Comment: Yes, but my question is how do I do if there is a success or not? I need to somehow tell the compiler the data insertion has been successful, are there any API that handle that?

Comment: then u have to do like this first check the internet connection is available or not once the net is available show the succuss message if its not then show the fial message

Comment: Do you know any built in functions to check that?

Answer (score 0):

On the success you can display the Alert View.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tiltle"
                                              message:@"Message"
                                              delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
```

as you are checking the posted data manually .You need to give back a response like a message in json to app like the following:

```
{
status = Done // for sucess OR ERROR for error;
}
```

and then you have to check that message in the app to see data is posted or not nad can render it as

```
    NSMutableDictionary *result = (NSMutableDictionary *)responseObject;
    NSString *errorMsg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result valueForKey:@"status"]];
    if([errorMsg isEqualToString:@"ERROR"])
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result valueForKey:@"status"]]
                                              message:@"Something went wrong..."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else
   {

   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result valueForKey:@"status"]]
                                   message:@"All done"
                                   delegate:nil
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
     }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks but how do I do if there is a success or not? I need to somehow tell the compiler the data insertion has been successful, are there any API that handle that?

Comment: As you wrote above "successfully inserts data".how did you check that ;are you checking directly in the database?

Comment: I just go into my myphpadmin and check my table, and it shows the names I inputted and added to the field.